# Gradle Build Failure with duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class

Tags: android, parse-platform, build.gradle

I have just added the `com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1` dependency to my project since the `ParseQueryAdapter` was missing from the Parse SDK and now when i try to build my project, i get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class
```

My build.gradle file is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.radioafrica.music"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
//    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
//    compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.1.jar')
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:1.2.1'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
    compile project(':library')
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm ParseQueryAdapter was missing from the Parse SDK?It same like It is duplicate .

Comment: Yes, it is missing. Hence the need to add the Parse UI library.

Comment: Or     compile project(':library')  the library contain it ?

Comment: No, that only has the Exoplayer library.

Comment: //    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.6.1@aar') {
//        transitive = true;
//    }  try remove it  or turn tansitive to false.

Comment: Or try clear project . I'm going to sleep.Bye.

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android  has gradle depend docs. You don't build with widget + okhttp + parseUI. The build guide from this project may help with your dupe dependencies

Comment: I can't download   compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.6.1@aar')  and I get no error.